# How to execute a correct cleanup of GPIO and SPI on Raspberry Pi using Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, spi

I'm experimenting with wireless communication using NRF24L01+ between Arduino and Raspberry Pi. I'm able to establish the connection and send the data to RPi but when I stop and start my program no data are received. No error or warning message is displayed. After reboot works everything fine so I think there is something wrong with my cleanup code.

Here is my code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import spidev
from libs.lib_nrf24 import NRF24


try:

    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

    pipes = [[0xE8, 0xE8, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1], [0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xF0, 0xE1]]
    radio = NRF24(GPIO, spidev.SpiDev())
    radio.begin(0, 25)
    radio.setPayloadSize(32)
    radio.setChannel(0x76)
    radio.setDataRate(NRF24.BR_250KBPS)
    radio.setPALevel(NRF24.PA_MIN)
    radio.setAutoAck(True)
    radio.enableDynamicPayloads()
    radio.enableAckPayload()
    radio.openReadingPipe(1, pipes[1])
    radio.printDetails()
    radio.startListening()

    while True:

        while not radio.available(0):
            time.sleep(1/100)

        receivedMessage = []
        radio.read(receivedMessage, radio.getDynamicPayloadSize())
        print("Received: {}".format(receivedMessage))

        print("Translating our received Message into unicode characters...")
        string = ""

        for n in receivedMessage:
            if (n >= 32 and n <= 126):
                string += chr(n)
        print("Our received message decodes to: {}".format(string))

finally:
    print("Performing cleanup...")
    radio.end()
    GPIO.cleanup()
    print("Cleanup done...")
```

The library lib_nrf24 I'm using is this one: https://github.com/BLavery/lib_nrf24

Output from `radio.printDetails()` is displayed correctly in both cases.

I'm stopping the program using Ctrl+C and both messages are printed - `Performing cleanup...` and also `Cleanup done...`

How should I perform the cleanup to be able to run my program multiple times without rebooting the RPi? Or is there some other error in my code?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I cant offer help at the moment, but I want to give you props for saying "data are". Most don't get this distinction.